# Socat and rich terminals (with Ctrl+C/Ctrl+Z/Ctrl+D propagation)

Tags: linux, bash, tty, job-control

`socat - exec:'bash -li',pty,stderr,ctty` -> `bash: no job control in this shell`

What options should I use to get fully fledged shell as I get with ssh/sshd?

I want to be able to connect the shell to everything socat can handle ([SOCKS 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#SOCKS_5), UDP, OpenSSL), but also to have a nice shell which correctly interprets all keys, various <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, tab completion, up/down keys (with remote history).

- Update 1: Found "setsid" socat option. It fixes "no job control". Now trying to fix <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
- Update 2:

  ```
  socat file:`tty`,raw,echo=0 exec:'bash -li',pty,stderr,setsid,sigint,sane
  ```

  . Not it handles <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> well, I can start Vim inside it, remote history is OK.

Comment: Looks like all requirements are met now. Now to mark the question as closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problems were:

1. Missing "setsid" option in right side of socat. It will cause bash not to be controller of session.
2. Using "-" in the left side of socat. The proper thing is `tty`,raw,echo=0.

Now I can have a shell over all things socat can support and can start vim/screen/ssh, interrupt `ping` with ^C, end `cat` with ^D and do everything else in that shell.

If bash breaks lines wrong and/or `vim` is too small or too big, you can use [termsize](https://github.com/akkana/scripts/blob/master/termsize) to fix it easily.

Comment: Using `STDIN:raw,echo=0` instead of `file:\`tty\`,raw,echo=0` worked better for me.  I was able to use this (using two socats with a unix domain socket in the middle) to get shell access to a container in a different network namespace.

Comment: @SethRobertson For playing with Linux namespaces, also see my other project: https://github.com/vi/dive

Comment: @SethRobertson, I use this way of starting something in other existing network namespace: `dived -J -S -T --setns /proc/12345/ns/net -- /bin/bash`. This way only network namespace gets set, everything else (other namespaces, controlling terminal, parent process) is preserved.