# Why does socat with rich terminal get killed with signal 9 on OSX?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, socat

I used the following command from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/123790/socat-and-rich-terminals-with-ctrlc-ctrlz-ctrld-propagation) to test out using socat to build a terminal with rich signals:

```
socat file:'/dev/tty',raw,echo=0 exec:'bash -li',pty,stderr,setsid,sigint,sane
```

On Linux, it worked fine and everything was as expected.

On OSX, I get the following output:

```
2023/03/24 22:15:52 socat[35049] E waitpid(): child 35050 exited on signal 9
```

**What causes OSX to kill the child here?
Is it possible to stop this from happening?**

Out of curiosity, I tried with `sudo` and got the same result so I can confirm it has anything to do with user permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with options and found that if `-i` is not passed, then the process does not get killed.

```
socat file:'/dev/tty',raw,echo=0 exec:'bash -l',pty,stderr,setsid,sigint,sane
```

What is curious is that it looks like bash is started as an interactive shell anyways, as we would expect because no commands are passed.

```
echo $-
himBH
```

Somehow, passing the `-i` option causes OSX to be angry even though it should have no effect.